# send email with attachments

Tags: c#, email, xaml, windows-runtime, attachment

My problem is very simple. I need to send e-mail with recipients and attachments which I generate in C#.

## 1 method:

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=" + emails + "&subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body);
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

It's ok but I cannot add attachments (only recipients)

## 2 method:

Using `DataTransferManager`. It's very cool but I can't add recipients.

Is there any method to solve my problem ?

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: You have tagged this with "windows-runtime" which can mean "WinRT".  Is this your intention, or are you writing something under C# meant to work from "normal" PCs?

Comment: @Kevin, DataTransferManager is available only for Modern UI apps for sharing content beetween apps (including content that can be mailed). So I am pretty sure that he talks about Modern UI apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid the limitations of the two methods that you have already tried:

- `mailto:` protocol doesn't allow adding attachments. Also you depend on what application the user has configured for handling this protocol. It might not work at all.
- You can't set the recipient for sharing. Also you can't be sure which app the user will select as the share target. He might post the content on a social network or use it some other way.

I think that using a web service to do this job as Antonio already suggested is the best way for sending emails from a Windows Store app non-interactively.

There's also a [third party SMTP component](http://www.limilabs.com/mail-for-windows-store) available which you can use for sending email. The downside of this approach is that you'll need the user to configure the SMTP setting for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no (easy) way to send e-mail from Modern UI application, only thing you can do is share content to be send and then user will choose if he or she wont to use mail client and choose recipients in mail client.

For some reason Microsoft didn't include that in WinRT API, IMO it's something that is surely needed, for example for alternative e-mail client in Modern UI.

Harder way would be implement smtp client, or much easier build some kind of web service that will send mails, or use an existing service like [mandrill.com](http://mandrill.com/)